# React - display variable number of rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table to which the user can add and remove rows. The HTML for a row is created by `this.displayRow()` and the number of rows is stored in `this.state.rowNr`. I would like to display `this.state.rowNr` rows, so something like this:

```
displayTableBody: function() {
    return(<div>
        {
            for(i = 0 ; i < this.state.rowNr ; i++) {
                this.displayRow();
            }
        }
    </div>);
}
```

However this is not valid JSX syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign an array containing the rows to a variable and render it inside your div:

```
displayTableBody: function() {
    var rows = Array.apply(null, Array(this.state.rowNr)).map(function(el) { return this.displayRow(); })
    return (<div> { rows } </div>);
}
```

Alternatively, using `lodash` (a JavaScript utility library):

```
displayTableBody: function() {
    var rows = _.times(this.state.rowNr).map(this.displayRow);
    return (<div> { rows } </div>);
}
```

The code `Array.apply(null, Array(this.state.rowNr))` creates an array of length `this.state.rowNr` with undefined values.

Each `undefined` value is then transformed (or *mapped*) to the result of the function `this.displayRow()`. I assume that this function returns an element containing a row.

Also check that the result of this function, `displayTableBody` is used in the `render` method.

Comment: I'm not sure why I have been downvoted after being accepted by the OP. Would you mind leaving a comment explaining why you downvoted me?

Comment: Reason for downvote: Use of `Array.apply` is clever but produces something you can't use, the undefineds within the array, just to be able to use `.map` as a fancy iterator (by discarding/not using `el` in your function body. Code is hard to read, understand and obscure and, IMO, not the preferred way of doing it.

Comment: Furthermore it'll be so much slower since you're doing a loop over the `rowNr` in order to create the array of undefineds and then doing map over the array again. Discussion is however moot since OP wanted a copy paste answer.

Comment: Are you really concerned about this type of premature optimization? Saying that it will be much slower is funny. Also, the `Array.apply ` is idiomatic -  while a for loop could be easier to understand (I agree with you), this one-liner is commonly seem is JavaScript code. I also provided an alternative way of initializing the array, using lodash/underscore. I don't want to sound rude, but this downvote make it seems that your ego is hurt.

Comment: My ego is far from hurt, I've been downvoted and unaccepted a whole heap of times - what I do think, however, is that doing the above, whilst it's working, does not help one bit - it is overly complex and hard to read and it's not a premature optimisation since by looking at it, you know it's bad and slow. There's a saying from the Python community. There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

Comment: Well, we both know it helped the OP :) Anyway, thanks for the feedback, although I still disagree about the *bad* and *slow* part.

Answer (score 1):

React can only render objects or arrays and not javascript expressions.

Move the for loop out of the return and do your computation there.

```
displayTableBody: function() {
   var rows = [];
   for(i = 0 ; i < this.state.rowNr ; i++) {
       rows.push(this.displayRow());
   }
   return <div>{rows}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
displayTableBody: function() {
    var rows = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.rowNr; i++) {
      rows[i] = this.displayRow();
    }

    return(<div>{rows}</div>);
}
```